# Can't access SelectedNode Value from asp Treeview in javascript

Tags: asp.net, treeview

I have an asp page that has a Treeview on it that is populated in code behind (so not data-bound).  As I expand the nodes eventually the list of item becomes so big that after the postback, I lose where I was in the tree.  So I've been looking into using client-side script to use `scrollIntoView` but all the examples of how to get the current selected node (the node I just expanded), seem to fail for me.

```
var elem = document.getElementById('navTree_SelectedNode');
alert(elem.value);
```

For me the `.value` is always null, as though no item has been selected.  I've tried calling this code on the `window.load` and also by running a script from the code-behind.  So I know there are lots of posts of this is how to do it, but I can't get an ID back of the item so I can then do a `document.getElementById()` on to then run the `scrollIntoView`.  Maybe I'm trying to access the value too early/late and it's not been set, so where would the best place for me to check this be?

I've also tried accessing it with:

```
var test = document.getElementById('navTree_Data.selectedNodeID');
```

and still no luck.

Just a thought, selected is the item I have just clicked on to expand, not Checked as the nodes have check boxes?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

The issue was being caused by the `.SelectAction` on my nodes being set to `TreeNodeSelectAction.Expand` when it should be set to `.SelectExpand`.